# Default.aspx is started instead of_ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013

I want to launch an ASP.NET MVC 5. I have the models, views and controllers folders with a file *ViewStart.cshtml* at the root of the project. When I run the program, I have that error : "Server error in application '/' not found".

when I add a file *Default.aspx*, there is no error; I deducted it executed only aspx files. Then I modified *Global.asax* like this :

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            /*AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);*/
            ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
        }
```

Then I deleted Default.aspx and restarted the application. I had this error :
Erreur HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden

How to launch *_ViewStart.cshtml* at starting ?

Here the controller code : *AccountController.cs* :

```
 public class HomeController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "")
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return LogOut();
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(Login model, string returnUrl = "")
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.Email, model.RememberMe);
                }

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username and/or password");
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult LogOut()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", null);
        }
    }
```

And *Web.config* at the root of the folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="CustomMemberShip">
      <providers> 
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomMemberShip"
             type="apruzz_qBugTrack.BusinessManagement.CustomMemberShip" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BugTrackLikeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.modele.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.modele.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.modele.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PC-Quentin;initial catalog=BugTrackLike;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Uncomment the `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` line for the `Application_Start()` method.
2. Change the start up page in the `Build` tab of the project properties. It should be set to something like `http://localhost:portnumber/{controller}/{action}`